# Google Play could not retrieve my VERSION CODE (Android)

Tags: android, google-play

I am updating my application in google play. However, the problem is when I try to upload a signed apk, Error Message occurs. **"Upload failed
You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 1."**

But as you can see in my android manifest, the version code is already 2. What seems to be the problem? I had already synchronized gradle, make project, rebuild project, clean project.  Updated the version code to 3, 4 and 5 then upload but it will still not accepted by google play. My other application works just fine when I upload the APK to alpha after changing the version code. But this application would not upload. Help would be highly appreciated.

Android Manifest file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.toksis.listapp.app"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName=".102" >
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.toksis.listapp.app.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.toksis.listapp.app.DonateBillingActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_donate_billing" >
    </activity>
</application>

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<compatible-screens>

    <!-- no small size screens -->


    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />

    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />

    <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />

    <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="213"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    `
</compatible-screens>

<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: Try to change this both value android:versionCode="2"     android:versionName=".102"

Comment: The version code need to be incremented each time you upload a new apk.

Comment: Make sure you're actually uploading the correct apk file. For instance, change the name of the file exported to something like `my_app_2.apk`

Comment: Why the down flag? I'm stock. That is why I am asking for help.

Comment: @Haresh, that is what i am doing. As I understand it, the version code is the only one important.

Comment: Reason for down vote is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Wow I could no longer ask a question :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using gradle.

Gradle **overrides** this value in Manifest, so pay attention what you have in your build.gradle script.

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionName xxx
        versionCode 2

     }
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you! 

apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

Comment: Weird... why would Android Studio not update my gradle?

Comment: @TheOne Android Studio doesn't change your gradle script.
Modify your script, changing the versionCode and the versionName with your values and rebuild the apk.

Comment: @TheOne No, it is the normal behavior.

The defaultConfig element configures core settings and entries in the manifest file (AndroidManifest.xml) dynamically from the build system. The values in defaultConfig override those in the manifest file.

So using gradle, your have to specify these values in your gradle script (you can also delete these values from Manifest).

Comment: Okay. The right thing to do next time is to update first Gradle and then Android Manifest.

Answer (score 1):

change the **versionCode to 2** in **build.gradle(Module: app)** file.
If you just change it in manifest file in gradle based softwares
gradle **versionCode is overwritten again to 1.**

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the problem you are facing. Better you try to get the version information on you side and then generate the signed apk to install.

To obtain version information, applications use the getPackageInfo(java.lang.String, int) method of PackageManager.

Else you have to contact to google play guys to ask the issue. They will surely help you because as you are saying there should not be any problem in uploading application after increasing the version code.

Try to change version name also